# Get gmail attachment's downloading URL?

Tags: ruby, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am fetching [Gmail Attachment](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/GmailV1/MessagePartBody.html) through [Gmail API](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService.html) using the `get_user_message_attachment` [method](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService.html#get_user_message_attachment-instance_method) , but the data it sends is in Base64 encoded form. I want to get the attachment's downloadable URL, which I can store and send to the frontend of my application. Is it possible to get the URL of the attachment in some way? I do not want to convert the Base64 string to a file on my server and then upload it somewhere and send that upload's link to the front-end.

```
@gmail_service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
#authorization stuff is done and then I fetch the attachment which is received as a Google::Apis::GmailV1::MessagePartBody response
resp = @gmail_service.get_user_message_attachment("myemail@google.com", message_id, attachment_id)
# resp.data contains the base64 encoded string
```

I want the attachment as a downloadable URL, so that I don't have to do the manual file conversion and uploading stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) method returns a [Message object](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message)

This object contains the body of the message base64 encoded.

[image]

If you want a downloadable url I suggest that you convert the Base64 string to a file on your server and then upload it somewhere and send that upload's link to the front-end.

There is no other option this is the data the API returns.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider providing a proxy endpoint on your server for your frontend. Then give your frontend a link to this endpoint with a messageId, and make your server download the Gmail message and stream it to your client.

This is Aqueduct(Dart) sample code:

1. Have a dedicated route for attachments (tempToken&fileName is optional, also contentType can be derived from attachment data):

> ..route('/attachments/:tempToken/:msgId/:attachmentId/:fileName').link(()
> => AttachmentsController(ctx))

2. The controller essentially loads an attachment by msgId&attachmentId and gives its content to a client:

> ```
> @Operation.get('tempToken', 'msgId', 'attachmentId', 'fileName') Future<Response> getAttachment(
>   @Bind.path('tempToken') String tempToken, //
>   @Bind.path('msgId') int msgId,
>   @Bind.path('attachmentId') String attachmentId,
>   @Bind.query('contentType') String contentType) async {
>
> ...
>
> final attachment = await mailbox.readAttachment(messageId,attachmentId);
>
> return Response.ok(attachment)
>   ..encodeBody = false
>   ..contentType = ContentType.parse(contentType);   }
> ```

3. We use Google provided Gmail API library. This is mailbox.readAttachment:

> ```
> @override
> Future<List<int>> readAttachment(String messageId, String attachmentId) async => (await _gmail.users.messages.attachments.get('me', messageId, attachmentId)).dataAsBytes;
> ```

Comment: interesting. Can you provide any useful resources to look more into this strategy? Plus, how is it going to solve the problem that I have base64url encoded data and I need to provide a file url to my frontend?

Comment: Not sure about a resource but might be able to share some code later in Scala or Dart as we use this approach in multiple apps. In your server add a GET endpoint for something like /attachments/<gmail_message_id> How does your frontend use it? An XHR request for the file or static <img src="/attachments/<gmail_message_id>" /> in html?

Comment: It will be fetched using an HTTP client in a react app. Please do share the code if it might be helpful in this scenario.